# KVM Suggestion?

Tags: mac-mini, xserve, kvm

I need to get a large rack mountable, 16 port or larger, cascadable, VGA KVM that works with Macs. I've tried the iogear GCS1716, which claims mac support, but refuses to display video from my xserves or minis. Support says it's because of the mini displayport to VGA adapters. I've tried Apple official ones and third party. Since no modern Macs come with VGA built-in, it seems iogear's attitude is "Sure, Apple devices are supported. Unless you do the thing required to actually use them. Then, they are not supported.". Natch.

I have another KVM from another brand that escapes me at the moment that works fine, but it not cascadable, so we have out grown it.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT - I've discovered since posting this that if the Apple machine is the only one plugged into the KVM it works fine. Go Fig.

EDIT 2 - I've now also discovered that if nothing is plugged into port 1, then Apple machines work fine, so long as you don't switch to a PC. Then you have to reset the KVM to get the Apple machines working again.

EDIT 3 - About a month ago this KVM full on failed, and the replacement works just fine with adapters and everything on all my machines. So it looks like it was marginal hardware all along, despite what support was telling me.

Comment: Are you actually still running Xserve? What models mac are you looking to control?

Comment: I have a late 2009 xserve, and several Mac Minis, the 2012-ish models. For our purposes (build boxes), the xserve and the older minis actually deliver better performance for the money than the latest iteration of minis since they switched to the dual-core i7s. Particularly since we need something that is reasonable to put into a rack. The pretty much excludes the current Pros, even though the price on those is enough to exclude them.

Comment: I should also add that we only use the KVM when we need real console access to the machines. The vast majority of the work is either automated or done via remote access of one kind or another. However, when we need the local access, we generally need it quickly and reliably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a 16-port rackmount KVM from Avocent (http://www.emersonnetworkpower.com/en-US/Products/KVM/LCD-Console-Trays/Pages/AvocentLCDConsoleTraywithKVM.aspx) that I use with two MacMini's, linux, and windows (and previously a 2009 Xserve). It works fine with the MacMini's using the VGA to Mini-DVI, and the USBIAC KVM cable. Unsure about cascading though, quickly glanced through the specs and I didn't see it mentioned; but I'll bet there is something for it.